# Should I request a question to be reopened in Meta sites?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, vote-to-reopen, on-hold

I've been meeting a lot of questions that are marked unclear. Although the tag says [on hold] which means the questions may be reopened, after some clarifications and editing which made the questions clear and good-quality, the question is not reopened. I wanted to raise the attention of these questions by casting a reopen vote, but as I do not have enough reputation I cannot do so.

Is it against the rules to request a question to be reopened in Meta sites? Should I do so? Will the question / request be too localized?

Comment: On math.SE we have a chat room dedicated to this (requests for close/reopen/delete/undelete votes). There is also a big-list meta thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By editing, the question will go into the reopen queue, where users with reopen privileges can reopen the question. Of course, if still unclear or low quality, it might not get reopened by the community.

---

> Is it against the rules to request a question to be reopened in Meta sites?

There are no hard rules about this.

> Should I do so?

Probably not. In particular if there is a fairly high volume of these. You might have more success bringing it into chat.

> Will the question / request be too localized?

Probably - but the larger issue here is the volume of such requests. You are risking annoying the meta community by repeatedly posting about questions that would be reopened in due time via the reopen queue. That is - by trying to solve a problem that isn't there.

Comment: Per-site meta tends to get **very** low traffic. Gathering five 3K users to review the Reopen might take weeks, and by then it's already long expired.

Comment: Catch-22 then, @Sha?

Comment: Yup. I was about to suggest flagging as "other" and explain why need to be reopened but not sure how  happy the site mods would be about it. (the few mods who visit the per-site meta, that is)

Comment: Different communities would probably want to handle this differently as well. Partly depending on volume (both general question volume, meta activity volume, moderation effort volume and reopen request volume). Too many variables here to give a "do it this way everywhere" answer.

Comment: @Oded so if I really have to reopen it or I think the question has the quality to be reopened, I do not need to do anything?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 - generally speaking, on sites that are large enough, no need. Take it up to chat if nothing happens for a few days.

Comment: @Oded Alright. Thanks.